# Adobe After Effects Plane tracking?

Tags: adobe, after-effects

I have this footage that I downloaded from iStock. It's [Flow chart and earth background](https://www.istockphoto.com/video/flow-chart-and-earth-background-gm166407540-21255891) footage. I wanted to add words similar to [this footage](https://www.istockphoto.com/video/flow-chart-and-business-background-gm166407543-21266258) in which words appears in blue boxes.

My idea is to create a null object, create motion tracking, attach tracking data to the null object, and then create text layers and link it to null object.

I tried several different motion tracking. I tried 3d motion tracking but it tracked too many points. I tried perspective corner pin tracking but there's a lot of contrast in the footage and the corners pins shake a bit as I analyze each frame. I would have to go through each frame to adjust each corner pin in order to prevent the shakiness. I tried planer tracking in mocha cc but I don't really understand how to get planer tracking to work.

How do you suggest I go about capturing the motion and linking the text layers to the motion/tracking data? I tried to find tutorials on youtube but I couldn't find the right one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when you say "3d motion tracking" do you mean the 3d camera tracker built in to ae? That would be the best way to do it, but "too many points" tells me you don't know how it works (the more the better). If you do mean the camera tracker I can guide you to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The (arguably) best way to do this is to use the built-in 3D camera tracker.
Once you get the solved camera ("create camera"), you find the correct plane using one of the solved tracker points (right-click on one of the points to bring up the menu), copy the position of the resulting null or solid and paste that into the layer you want (I'm assuming animated text), adjust the orientation and you're basically there. I just did it with the watermarked footage:
http://www.crgreen.com/misc/stackoverflowStuff/flow-chart-and-earth-background-video-id166407540.htm_h.mp4

Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions but I didn't get any results. The steps I took are:
1. Select the footage, click on "Track Camera", and wait for the footage to be analyzed. 
2. Tracker points will appear. Select one of the points and right-click to bring up the menu. Click "Create Null and Camera".
3. Create a text layer. Click on "3D" in the layer and link it to "Track Null 1"
4. Copy Orientation from "3D Tracker Camera" and paste it in text layer
I still couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: what do you mean by 'Click on "3D" in the layer and link it to "Track Null 1"'? You're not linking it; you should be copying the position from the null and pasting it into your text layer. But you'll still probably need to adjust it to make sure it is on the **correct plane**

Comment: The orientation of the text layer should be done by eye after you get it into the correct position. Remember, the basic idea here is that the camera is doing all the work. Once you get a "solve" that works (this is the last stage after "analyzing" and propagating trackers where trackable features are), you just need to find the correct planes on which to put objects. In your case, the objects you're adding aren't doing additional moving in that space.